# STM32F4 LIS3MDL Magnetometer Hard-Iron Effect Elimination

Tags: sensor, stm32f4, keil, stm32cubemx, magnetometer

I am using LIS3MDL 3 axis magnetometer sensor for car detection project. while I am using raw data, I understand that if sensor is exposed to hard-iron effect then this sensor can not read old values.

so how can I eliminate this effect and calibate sensor for stabile working.

thank you for all.

Answer (score 1):

Without having read it deeply, [this document](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4246.pdf) seems a good way to do it. Is the first result in google, by the way.

Comment: I have already found it, but I want to ask for something easier.

Comment: I think there is no easy way to do it. Maybe you can adapt the code used in the 9-DOF Razor IMU:

https://github.com/Razor-AHRS/razor-9dof-ahrs